# XMLHttpRequest() Not Working with IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

The script below is working fine with Firefox and Chrome but I cant seem to get it to work with ie, tried everything even lowered the security on my browser to see if was that blocking it, but i still cant get it to work.

```
function postData() {

    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var url = "/scripts/remove_fr.php";

    var params = "";

    http.open("GET", url, true);



    //Send the proper header information along with the request

    http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);

    http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");



    http.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state changes.

        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {



        }

    }



    http.send(params);



}



    $("#qwerty").click(function () {

      $('#qwerty').remove();

    });



</script>
```

Comment: IE version? Error? What is not working? What is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're already using jQuery, so use [jQuery's AJAX utility functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)! Don't try to roll your own; the XMLHttpRequest API is ugly and annoying.

I'd like to provide sample code, but right now what you've got amounts to simply:

```
$.get("/scripts/remove_fr.php");
```

which isn't much of an example. ;)

Answer (score 12):

Below IE7, it uses `ActiveXObject` objects instead of `XMLHttpRequest`
So your code should be like this:

```
function postData() {
    var http;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
         // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
         // code for IE6, IE5
         http = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    var url = "/scripts/remove_fr.php";
    var params = "";
    http.open("GET", url, true);

   //Send the proper header information along with the request
   http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
   http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
   http.onreadystatechange = function() { //Call a function when the state changes.
       if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {

       }
   }
   http.send(params);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this code , this gets the XMLHttpRequest based on the browser.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
```

Please refer link for details [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp)